# How to compare current date to given date in MySQL

Tags: sql, jsp

How to compare current date to given date in MySQL I am using like that code but it's not working.

```
  <%
    rs=st.executeQuery("select approcode,approemail,appromon,approvemon,approtue,approvetue,approwed,approvewed,approthr,approvethr,approfri,approvefri,approsat,approvesat,commen,months,SUM(nol) from `pushkalit`.`approval`WHERE (CONVERT( `approcode` USING utf8 ) LIKE '%"+user+"%') AND appromon=DATE(now()) OR approtue=DATE(now()) OR  approwed=DATE(now()) ");
     // i have given in mysql, appromon varchar(30).....so on dateformat have dd/MM/yyyy
    %>
```

Comment: look at answer pls...

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it like

```
DATE(NOW()) = DATE(duedate)
```

Will compare only the date part.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this to simple code asL:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: always results in full table scan, even if there is an INDEX on `myDate`

Answer (score 0):

See [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT 
    approcode, approemail, appromon, approvemon, approtue,approvetue, approwed, approvewed, approthr, approvethr, approfri, approvefri, approsat, approvesat, commen, months, SUM(nol) 
FROM `pushkalit`.`approval`
WHERE (CONVERT(`approcode` USING utf8) LIKE '%"+user+"%')
   AND ( appromon  = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%d/%m/%Y") 
   OR    approtue  = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%d/%m/%Y") 
   OR    approwed  = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%d/%m/%Y") )
```

Note that i inserted parens around your `OR` conditions, because i think this is actually what you intended to query.

Comment: While looking more complicated than the solution in the other answers, this query method can be much faster - as MySQL may be able to do an INDEX based lookup. In this special case / in your query the `LIKE "%username%"` is already forcing a full table scan, so you won't notice any difference, though.

Comment: how to select less than and equals to current date when i am using like that <= but show only less than value are showing only not equal

Comment: @DeepakSingh to select rows with a date in a specific range, you should really change your table definition and convert those fields to a real `DATE` datatype. If you do this, you can query such things like: `WHERE mydate BEFORE '2014-03-17'` or `WHERE mydate BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31'`

Comment: @DeepakSingh PS: welcome to StackOverflow. if you found this or another answer helpful, please upvote it and accept it as solution. Please read the [Getting Started](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @DeepakSingh please read [Getting Started](http://stackoverflow.com/help) - it's all explained there. Next to the answer you find up and down buttons (as well as a checkmark). You can use those to up/downvote. The checkmark accepts the answer as solution.